# Button to next view controller

Tags: ios, swift, uibutton, selector

I want to create a Button that presents another view controller when it is tapped.
I am trying to to this via selector but when I click the button I get a Thread1: signal SAGABRT error.
So I commented out the presenting and just put in a print to console-statement. I also get the same error. :(

My code is the following:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    var menuView = UIView()
    var newPlayButton = UIButton()
    var newPlayImage = UIImage(named: "new_game_button_5cs")
    var newPlayImageView = UIImageView(image: UIImage(named: "new_game_button_5cs"))
    newPlayButton.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, newPlayImageView.frame.width, newPlayImageView.frame.height)
    newPlayButton.setImage(newPlayImage, forState: .Normal)
    newPlayButton.addTarget(self, action:"showNewPlay:", forControlEvents: UIControlEvents.TouchUpInside)
    menuView.addSubview(newPlayButton)
    self.view.addSubview(menuView)
}
func showNewPlay(sender:UIButton!) {
    //var vc = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("newGameID") as ViewController
    //self.presentViewController(vc, animated: false, completion: nil)
    println("Button tapped")
}
```

Comment: are you sure vc is not nil? you should check that before pushing, since presentViewController requires UIViewController, not UIViewController?

Comment: ... it does not event show the "Button tapped" message... So I first want to see that message before fixing bugs I do not know they do exist (the vc-Code is commented out)

Comment: You're passing a `UIButton!` as your sender.
Try passing `AnyObject`type to your function.
You can try passing `Selector("showNewPlay")` as argument in your `addTarget`function call.

Comment: How do you even see your button since you never add menuView to your controller's view? Also, menuView has no frame set, so your button shouldn't be touchable. Is this your actual code?

Comment: Oh, forgot to add the line where I add the it as subview :D But I have it in my code.
Good idea with the AnyObject and Selector("showNewPlay")... but sadly didn't solve the problem :(

Comment: When I try your code, the button isn't touchable (because it is outside the bounds of its superview which has a zero frame). If I set a frame for menuView, it is touchable, and I get no errors.